# How do i check if a string format is valid while reading from a text file in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm quite new to programming in C++ and i'm trying to learn how do we validate if a given word/string in a text file is in the right format. I have text file that contains a line like this:**Car,Red,ZX342DC.** The line contains the type of vehicle,color,plate. While i'm reading the line I want to perform a check on the string **ZX342DC** such that it must have 2 upper case letters followed by 3 numbers and 2 upper case letters before assigning this string to a string object. If none of these conditions are met, i want to flag out an error saying there's an invalid entry in line number-" ", ignore the line and move on to the next line in the file.

Comment: What's the problem with the code you've got?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow, please, before asking, read [ask]

Comment: I dont know why this has been put on hold. It's amply clear what the user wanted to do: validate a string against a desirable pattern. He/she just didn't know how to go about it. This isnt a "what's wrong with my code" type question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I give out my answer, it's yet unclear that what name your input text file has. Let's suppose the name of your text file is `test.txt` and it locates right within the same directory as the C++ source file, `test.cpp`.

> test.txt

```
Car,Red,ZX342DC
```

> test.cpp

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Let's start with variable declaration and initialization

    // First you have to open the text file,
    // for which you need `ifstream`.
    // It is responsible for decoding text files.
    ifstream ifs("test.txt");

    // Provide a temporary storage for each line
    string line;

    // Regular expression pattern object
    // This is what you need
    // in order to validate each line
    // and extract data from each line,
    regex p("(\\w+),(\\w+),([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}[A-Z]{2})");

    // Match object
    smatch m;

    // Check if the file stream is opened
    // otherwise you might have some problems
    // to continue the following steps
    if (ifs.is_open())
    {
        // Then you need to traverse over each line in the file.
        for (int lineNum = 1;
                getline(ifs, line);
                lineNum++)
        {
            // Validate the line
            if (regex_search(line, m, p) && m.size() > 3)
            {
                cout << "Pattern matched." << endl;
                cout << endl;

                string vehicle = m.str(1);
                string color = m.str(2);
                string plate = m.str(3);

                cout << "Vehicle:\t"    << vehicle << endl;
                cout << "Color  :\t"    << color << endl;
                cout << "Plate  :\t"    << plate << endl;

                // You can insert some codes here to handle the results

                cout << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cerr << "There's an invalid entry in line number - " << lineNum << "!" << endl;
            }
        }

        // Always remember to close a stream
        // before exiting the program
        // otherwise you may suffer from **memory leakage**
        ifs.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "Fail to open input file!" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Reference:

- [std::ifstream::ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/)
- [std::getline (string)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)
- [regex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/)
- [C++ Regular Expressions with std::regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/stdregex.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. Although, I haven't had much experience with regular expressions, this is simpler and easier to understand and implement. I would like to learn more on regular expressions and if you could point me to sources for future references it would be helpful . Thanks again.

Comment: @DSNadig The constructor of class `regex` takes a string parameter `str` whose content must obey the syntax of regular expression in ECMAScript (aka. JavaScript) **by default**.

Comment: You can change the default behaviour by altering flags when invoking the constructor of class `regex` according to [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/basic_regex/basic_regex/).

Comment: I guess you ain't familiar with JavaScript either. But I still recommend you take a look at JavaScript [RegExp object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp). Let me know if there is anything not clear about regular expression in the tutorial.

Comment: Also take a look at [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/stdregex.html).

Answer (score 4):

You can do something along the following lines:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<regex>

int main()
{
  std::string input{"Car,Red,ZX342DC"};
  std::regex regex{R"(([[:alpha:]]+),([[:alpha:]]+),([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}[A-Z]{2}))"};

  std::smatch match;
  if (std::regex_search(input, match, regex)) {
    std::cout << "Found" << "\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "Did Not Found" << "\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As others have stated, Regular Expressions are a good way to approach this.  However, for a complete beginner in C++, they can be a bit overwhelming if you are not familiar with them in other languages.

Here is an alternative that doesn't use Regular Expressions:

```
inline bool IsInRange(char c, char lower, char upper)
{
    return ((c >= lower) && (c <= upper));
}

inline bool IsUpper(char c)
{
    return IsInRange(c, 'A', 'Z');
}

inline bool IsDigit(char c)
{
    return IsInRange(c, '0', '9');
}

bool IsValidPlate(const std::string &plate)
{
    return (
        (plate.size() == 7) &&
        IsUpper(plate[0]) &&
        IsUpper(plate[1]) &&
        IsDigit(plate[2]) &&
        IsDigit(plate[3]) &&
        IsDigit(plate[4]) &&
        IsUpper(plate[5]) &&
        IsUpper(plate[6])
    );
}

struct VehicleInfo
{
    std::string vehicle;
    std::string color;
    std::string plate;
};

bool ParseVehicleInfo(const std::string &line, VehicleInfo &info)
{
    std:istringstream iss(line);
    return (
        std::getline(iss, info.vehicle, ',') &&
        std::getline(iss, info.color, ',') &&
        std::getline(iss, info.plate) &&
        IsValidPlate(info.plate)
    );
}

...

std::ifstream inputFile("file.txt");
std::string line;
int lineNum = 0;

while (std::getline(inputFile, line))
{
    ++lineNum;

    VehicleInfo info;

    if (!ParseVehicleInfo(line, info))
    {
        std::cout << "invalid data on line " << lineNum << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        // use info as needed...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

What you are looking for is called ["Regular Expressions"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), or more commonly, Regex. C++11 offers Regex as a standard library feature [2](https://www.regular-expressions.info/stdregex.html).